# Is there a way to toggle TLS settings using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, security, ssl, automation, settings

[image]

Can I toggle these security settings using Powershell? I was hoping I could run a simple script to do it, since it must be applied to hundreds of computers

Comment: Have a look at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

Comment: this `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'tls12, tls11, tls'` will set things for the current script. otherwise you will need to do as f6a4 pointed out and make changes in the registry.

Comment: If I can't find it in this directory does it mean I can't access these setting through powershell at all?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi) for the registry properties you need to upate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set-Location HCKU:
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -Name SecureProtocols -Value 2688
```

This enables all 3 TLS protocols.
Thanks f6a4 for pointing me in the right direction